# Avoid repetition in the association table of a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, optimization, many-to-many, repeat

I have the following scenario. I want to keep a list of addresses that a user was going through. For this I have created the following data model (very simplified).

```
pearson -> | id | name | genre | birthdate |
    (id) -> PK
address -> | id | zip_code | line_1 | line_2 | coutry |
    (id) -> PK
pearson_address -> | pearson_id | address_id | from_date | to_date |
    (pearson_id, address_id, from_date) -> PK
    (pearson_id) -> FK
    (address_id) -> FK
```

In this way, with the `from_date` and the `to_date` I can know by the addresses through which a person was passing. But, my question is the following. There is not much repeated information? In this way the `pearson_id` and the `address_id` would be repeating constantly for each date range.

```
| pearson_id | address_id |  from_date  |   to_date   |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----------- | ----------- |
|      1     |     2      |  2018-02-01 |  2018-09-10 |
|      1     |     3      |  2018-02-10 |  2018-12-13 |
|      1     |     2      |  2018-12-13 |  2019-02-11 |
|      1     |     3      |  2019-02-11 |     NULL    |
```

Is this ok or would I need to create another table to relate the association of `pearson_id` and `address_id` with the date ranges?

Comment: "addresses a user is going through" -- Is that like moving from one house to another?  And sometimes moving back?  Seems like "moving back" is rare enough to not worry about the "duplication".

Comment: Yes, it's that. Sorry for my English. So it is ok. Thank you.